# What is the average distance between two randomly chosen points on a Sierpiński triangle?

Tags: geometry, statistics, fractals

Since a [Sierpiński triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpi%C5%84ski_triangle) is made up of three smaller versions of itself, an algorithm made to pick random points on the triangle might go like this:

1. Select one of the three Sierpiński triangles inside the larger Sierpiński triangle
2. Repeat step 2 with the smaller Sierpiński triangle

It will continue getting more specific and will eventually narrow down to a point. If you continue picking two points like this, what will be the average distance? (Euclidian Metric)

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself, even if you haven't made much progress.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far could you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question will likely be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Clarifications don't belong in the comments.

Comment: I like this question.  I suggest you do first a simpler one:  Let $X$ be **one** randomly chosen point, let $A$ be (say) the top vertex, compute the expected distance $\mathbb E[d(X,A)]$.  Once you do this, then do your problem in terms of it.

Comment: Also: do you want the average distance in the Euclidean metric, or do you want the average distance following a path inside the Sierpinski Triangle?  My hint is for the latter.

Comment: I don't understand how you can do it in the latter, but I'm talking about the former Euclidian metric.

Comment: I believe https://www.acmicpc.net/problem/22222 mentions this constant, and names a mathematician that found an efficient way to compute it, Moomin Yoo Ji-ae. Google translated site: https://www-acmicpc-net.translate.goog/problem/22222?_x_tr_sl=auto&_x_tr_tl=en

Comment: That same site acmicpc shows that only 8 people have computed this constant to 222 digits, it starts with 0.4227021810348385578571.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how to do this analytically, but I did a simulation, assuming that the original triangle is equilateral of side $1$.  With one million trials, I got a $99\%$ confidence interval of $$(0.42238756083753565, 0.4234628881174311)$$

I started with $$(1,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,0,1)$$ as the vertices of the triangle in barycentric coordinates.  Then $30$ times, I chose one of the coordinates uniformly at random, and computed the vertices of the smaller triangle as the average of the chosen vertex and the old vertices.  For example, if the first vertex chosen were $(1,0,0)$ the new triangle would have coordinates $$(1,0,0),\left(\frac12,\frac12,0\right),\left(\frac12,0,\frac12\right)$$
After $30$ samples, I took the average of the vertices as the chosen point.

For each trial, I chose two points, and computed the Euclidean distance between them using the formula from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system#Distance_between_points).  Since I assumed that the side lengths of the triangle are all $1$, this is simply$$d=\sqrt{\frac{x^2+y^2+z^2}2}$$ where $x,y,z$ are the coordinates of the difference between the two chosen points, treated as vectors.

It seemed to me at first that one should be able to do this analytically.  If the coordinates of the $n$th triangle are $(X_n, Y_n, Z_n)$ then $X_{n+1}$ is equally likely to be any of $X_n,\ \frac{X_n+Y_n}2,\ \frac{X_n+Z_n}2$.  I haven't made any progress, though.  This may just be because I'm not thinking clearly, but as I'm typing this it occurs to me that, since the Sierpiński gasket is a fractal, perhaps the distributions functions of X,Y,Z are singular, so that we can't hope for analytic expressions.  I'm going to compute the distribution of $X_n$ for small $n$ and see if that gives me any ideas.

For completeness, here's the simulation script:

```
from sys import argv
from random import choices
from math import sqrt

def main(trials, samples):
    total = 0
    total2 = 0
    for _  in range(trials):
        x = pickPoint(samples)
        y = pickPoint(samples)
        # Triangle side length are all 1
        v =  [(z[0]-z[1])**2 for z in zip(x,y)]
        d = sqrt(sum(v)/2)  # Euclidean distance
        total += d
        total2 += d*d
    mean = total/trials
    variance = total2/trials - mean**2
    sigma = sqrt(variance/trials)
    return mean, sigma

def pickPoint(samples):
    V = [(1,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,0,1)]
    s = choices(range(3), k=samples)
    for k in s:
        v = V[k]
        V = [tuple((z[0]+z[1])/2 for z in zip(v,V[k])) for k in range(3)]  
    return [(V[0][k]+V[1][k]+V[2][k])/3 for k in range(3)]
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    trials = int(argv[1])
    samples = int(argv[2])
    mu, sigma = main(trials, samples)
    print(f'Mean = {mu}')
    print(f'sigma = {sigma}')
    print(f'{trials} trials')
    print(f'Sample depth = {samples}')
    delta = 2.576*sigma
    print(f'99% confidence interval: ({mu-delta}, {mu+delta})')
```

When I ran this with parameters `1000000 30` it produced the output

```
Mean = 0.4229252244774834
sigma = 0.00020872035712257242
1000000 trials
Sample depth = 30
99% confidence interval: (0.42238756083753565, 0.4234628881174311)
```